# What functions $f: A \to B$ and $g: B \to A$, satisfy a restriction such that $f$ is not invertible but $f \circ g=id_B$?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations

I am caught up on the notation of $id_B$. I'm thinking that $f=x^2$, or something along those lines, but not so sure as to what $g$ may be.

Comment: In order to have $f \circ g = id_B$, $f$ must be onto but necessarily 1-1, and $g$ must be 1-1 but not necessarily onto.

Comment: Try drawing some pictures. Let $B$ be a one point space and $A$ be a two point space.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I think you meant not necessarily one to one.

Comment: sorry, I've seen that shorthand so many times...

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Would $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x$ satisfy this? Since $g$ would be one to one, and $f$ would be onto?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I can only think of things then like $f=x/2$ and $g=2x$, but in that case $f$ is invertible.

Comment: The $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = \sqrt x$ example you mentioned in one of the comments is a good one; just figure out what your choice of sets $A$ and $B$ should be.

Comment: $x/2$ and $2x$ will also work for a smart choice of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein It seems that I should interchange the two, so that $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and $g(x)=x^2$ such that the sets $A=\mathbb{Z}_\geq0$ and $B=\mathbb{Z}_\geq0$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11868/discussion-between-azovax-and-dustan-levenstein)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per our chat discussion:

Let $A = \mathbb R$, $B = \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$, and define $f: A \to B$ by $x \mapsto x^2$, and $g: B \to A$ by $x \mapsto \sqrt x$. Then $f \circ g$ is the identity function on $B$, but $f$ is not one to one.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* If $f\circ g=\operatorname{id}_B$ then $g$ in injective and $f$ is surjective.

Comment: What is $id_B$ though? Is that the output of a given $x$ of $g(x)$?

Comment: @Azovax: $id_B$ is the function that takes every element $b\in B$ to itself.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** Since $f \circ g$ is onto, $f$ must be onto.

**Hint 2:** If $f: A \to B$ an onto function, try to prove that there exists some $g: B \to A$ such that

$$f(g(x))=x \,.$$

Note that for each $x$, you have $g(x)= ??$ means $f(??)=x$...

Comment: What is $id_B$ though? That is what I don't understand. I want to say the functions $f=x^2$ and $g=\sqrt{x}$ are the answers, but that doesnt seem right.

Comment: @Azovax $id_B$  is the function $id_B: B \to B, id_B(x)=x$... And your example works if you interchange $f$ and $g. Very important, you need to specify your sets $A=??$ and $B=??$...

Comment: So $A=\mathbb{Z}_\geq0$ and $B=\mathbb{Z}_\geq0$?

Comment: @Azovax Not a good choice, the imagine of $\sqrt{x}$ is not inside $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$.

Comment: So $A$ would stay the same, but $B=\mathbb{R}_\geq0$?

Comment: @Azovax But then $x^2$ may not be in $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: So both sets are $\in \mathbb{R}_\geq0$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11870/discussion-between-azovax-and-n-s)

Answer (score 1):

Let$$f(x)=|x|,g(x)=x$$
where $A=\mathbb{R},B=\mathbb{R}_+$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $B\subset A$, $B\ne A$, choose $b$ in $B$ and define $g(x)=f(x)=x$ for every $x\in B$ and $f(x)=b$ for every $x$ in $A\setminus B$. Then $f\circ g=\mathrm{id}_B$ but $f$ is not invertible.